# Can not make a line break in confirmPopup message - primeNg

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using primeNG v11 and I need to make a break line in my text message of the confirm popup. I've tried the \n and 
 but doesn't work.

My text message contains two phrases witch makes the popup too long.

```
export class ConfirmPopupDemo {

    constructor(private confirmationService: ConfirmationService) {}

    confirm(event: Event) {
        this.confirmationService.confirm({
            target: event.target,
            message: 'phrase 1 \n  phrase 2',
            icon: 'pi pi-exclamation-triangle',
            accept: () => {
                //confirm action
            },
            reject: () => {
                //reject action
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `<br>` instead of `\n`?

Comment: I tried it didn't work

Comment: Maybe you need to trust the string with the [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/guide/security#trusting-safe-values) to render the br Tag correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Add below to your css file (most probably styles.css)

```
.p-confirm-popup-message {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

then it will respect "\n"

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding `<pre></pre>` in the message like this.

```
export class ConfirmPopupDemo {

    constructor(private confirmationService: ConfirmationService) {}

    confirm(event: Event) {
        this.confirmationService.confirm({
            target: event.target,
            message: '<pre>phrase 1\nphrase 2</pre>',
            icon: 'pi pi-exclamation-triangle',
            accept: () => {
                //confirm action
            },
            reject: () => {
                //reject action
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I had to add ::ng-deep to get working...

```
::ng-deep .p-confirm-popup-message {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```